# run script before html is loaded vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to test if the user has login or not, if not he will return to login page.
I want the script that check if the user has login to be executed before html (or template) load.
I have tried

```
beforeCreate()
```

and other things, but html still load before the script run.
this is my code

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("email") == undefined) location.href = "/";
```

edit
I made this vue project using CLI so I dont have the normal index.html with head and body where i can simply add script anywhere outside vue.

Answer (score 0):

try checking if your condition matches before initiating vue instance and initiate it after satisfying the condition like this:

```js
if(sessionStorage.getItem("email") == undefined) {
   location.href = "/";
} else {
   var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
         message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: I made this vue project using CLI so i don't think i can use that, also i am using router.

Comment: why cant ? add it in main.js

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't considered "best practice" to implement security code using JavaScript. If a user turns off JavaScript in their browser, they have effectively bypassed your security.

Instead, use server-side code to detect if the current user is logged in, and if not, send an HTML redirect to the login page instead of the normal HTML content.

Pseudo code (as you haven't specified any server-side language):

```
if(userLogin <> true)
    Return HtmlRedirect("YourLoginPage")
...
Return CuurrentPage
```

This method prevents any HTML being sent to the user if they are not authorised to see it.

Comment: If you absolutely must use JavaScript, ensure any redirect code is in the HEAD of the HTML page, so it can be executed before the page is rendered in the browser.

Comment: There is a server-side check, there is no problem or error i have, i just want to make it better. i am new to vuejs so maybe there is something i miss

Comment: If you already have a server-side check to prevent the HTML being sent to the client, then any JS code you add will be irrelevant, as it should never execute in the client browser. It will only add unused code to every secured page for no reason - admittedly, it will be a small increase, not likely to make much difference to the client, but if the code generates any errors in the future (as libraries and standards are updated), then you have created a bug that would be difficult to track down. I would suggest there is no need to add any JS code for this purpose, if it can never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Dragonlaird said mentioning that it is not a best practice to handle it from the client-side. However, I think you have to try `beforeMount` or `beforeUpdate` instead of `beforeCreate` since you need to do the stuff before HTML (or template) load. According to the Vue.js documentation,

1. `beforeMount`:
   It is called right before the mounting begins: the render function is about to be called for the first time.
   But this hook(`beforeMount`) is not called during server-side rendering.
2. `beforeUpdate`:
   It is called when data changes before the DOM is patched. This is a good place to access the existing DOM before an update, e.g. to remove manually added event listeners.

This hook is also not called during server-side rendering, because only the initial render is performed server-side.

For further information please refer Vue.js documentation.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks